# Report over PresenceServiceRouting

Tags: reporting, omnichannel

I have all the routing been done by routing skills, so the omni-supervisor have many many many information. Is it possible to create a report that shows all the information present in omni-supervisor and so that I can combine filters?

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you're using skills based routing. Is your question that you want to report on the skills required by Agents to respond to cases Omni-Channel assigned to them? You then perhaps want to be able to filter by skill? If not, what kinds of filters do you want to apply? CaseType? Chat, Email, etc? Please clarify the scope of your question.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I want a report that list the cases pending distribution to agents/ skills and the possibility to filter by the skills necessary to the distribution. For example, to receive case 1 an agent needs to have Skill A, Skill B and Skill C. To receive case 2 an agent needs to have Skill A, Skill B and Skill C. I want a report that lists the case, like omni-channel and the possibility to filter by Skill A and Skill D.